# Preventing impulsive downvotes with a timer

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

- You write a quick answer and post it.
- You write an answer, post it and then OP updates the question
- You accidentally post the question/answer before it's ready

All these cases have one thing frequently in common:

- A storm of downvotes

It has happened to everyone. And frequently, those downvoting people don't even read your updated answer - they've already moved on.

Now, I'm not even trying to go into the whole "obligatory downvote explanation" story, but rather I'd like suggest a way to prevent this.

Do you think it might be a good idea to add a timer before something freshly posted can be downvoted? 30 seconds, 1 minute... Whatever would work the best.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, that one didn't show up when I searched for similar ones.

Comment: Yeah, probably because it's not tagged with [meta-tag:down-votes].

Comment: I just don't get it why is this question so bad... I understand that people don't like the idea, but I don't think (especially after a few years on SO) that it's a badly formed question. Is the community so different here?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @CareBear Ahhhhh, thank you so much!!! That explains everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You write a quick answer and post it.

In this case, it's **entirely your fault** for posting a bad answer without reading over it first. The downvoters are doing a perfectly good job downvoting your bad answer, and they are not obligated to sit and wait for 10 more minutes to see if you're going to fix it.

> You write an answer, post it and then OP updates the question

This is definitely not a problem that you're going to solve by adding a timer or something preventing downvotes; this is a misuse of the editing system by the OP. Edits should not invalidate an existing answer. So, simply roll back the edit.

> You accidentally post the question/answer before it's ready

I'm curious as to how you can manage to accidentally move the mouse all the way down to the "Post Answer" button and click it at the perfectly right time, so I'm fairly sure that this is really just the same as your first item. You're so wound up in trying to get the first answer that you instinctively hit the button before you're ready. So try to create a new habit: *Before* you post your answer, read over the entire thing just once (or at least skim it) and make sure it's correct and there are no errors.

However, if you do somehow accidentally post an answer mid-sentence, simply delete it, edit it to finish the answer, and then undelete it again.

Comment: Premature Posting does occasionally happen. For example, when you hit the “tab” key, but forget that it doesn't increase indentation. Instead, focus jumps to the next field in the HTML form for the answer … which is the submit button. Upon the next “return”, the answer is posted.

Answer (score 7):

> All these cases have one thing frequently in common:

...they're a symptom of being in a hurry.

Nothing wrong with that, mind you - in today's fast-paced world, what with all the twitters and FGITWs and jet airplanes, seems like *everyone* is in a hurry.

But like everything we enjoy, there are costs. And in this particular situation, the cost is a higher risk of downvotes if you make a mistake.

Of course, the upside is a potentially-higher chance of *upvotes* if you *don't* err. Whether or not the risk is worth the reward, that's a decision you'll have to make for yourself.

Comment: +1 All true, there's also one more reason for a hurry - competition. Sometimes you just know there will be 5 more  people coming up with a good answer, but it feels great to be the first, doesn't it?

Comment: For sure - and as always, [competition has its risks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uud7rcwhI5U&t=1m5s).

Comment: Btw. you didn't say whether it's a good or a bad idea, which is the point of answering.

Comment: It's unnecessary - that's really all there is to it. If you want a timer *for yourself*, just write your post in a text editor and spend 30 seconds proofreading before you copy it onto the question.

Comment: That's so in contrast to, say, how comment upvote cancelling works (among other features)...